# Why does setItems function (useState hook) work when used inside a function inside useEffect but not when it is used inside useEffect directly?

Tags: reactjs, use-state

In the example why does `setItems` work here:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(
        `https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters`
      );
      setItems(result.data);
    };
    fetchItems();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <div key={item.char_id}>{item.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-butterfly-2upbp

but not here (instead it returns a TypeError items is undefined):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(
        `https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters`
      );
      return result;
    };
    const result = fetchItems();
    setItems(result.data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <div key={item.char_id}>{item.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-lake-7iji5

Comment: because `fetchItems` returns a promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `then` function to get the result.

```
fetchItems().then(result => setItems(result.data))
```

You declared an async function in your `useEffect` hook thus `fetchItems` will return a promise. But since `useEffect` function argument does not accept async functions, it's better to resolve the promise first before setting the state

Answer (score 1):

```
const fetchItems = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get(
    `https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters`
  );
  return result;
};

const result = fetchItems(); // result is a promise.
setItems(result.data);
```

In the above snippet, `fetchItems` is an async function so it returns a promise. So when you use `result.data`, you're trying to access `data` on the Promise but not on the resolved value.

Answer (score 1):

The main reason is because `fetchItems` returns a promise (async/await).

But there is another problem because you would need to wait that the promise was resolved so you need to add `await` to `fetchItems` but this cannot be done because `useEffect` must return a clean-up function.

CORRECT:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  // Also it's valid to create it directly inside the useEffect
  const fetchItems = useCallback(async () => {
    const result = await axios.get(
        `https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters`
    );
    setItems(result.data);
  }, [setItems])

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchItems();
  }, [fetchItems]);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <div key={item.char_id}>{item.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

WRONG:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  // WRONG: useEffect is not a clean-up function.
  useEffect(async () => { 
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get(
        `https://www.breakingbadapi.com/api/characters`
      );
      return result;
    };
    const result = await fetchItems();
    setItems(result.data);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map(item => (
        <div key={item.char_id}>{item.name}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```